# IMAP takes 15 seconds to load

Tags: php, imap

On my local machine using XAMPP, I'm opening an office365 account via `imap_open`, displaying the number of messages in the inbox and then closing IMAP.

```
$hostname = "{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX";
$imap = imap_open($hostname, 'email', 'password');
$message_count = imap_num_msg($imap);
echo $message_count;
imap_close($imap);
```

Every time I run this script it takes a whopping 15 seconds to complete. When I upload it to my hosting at GoDaddy, it takes about 12 seconds which is still an insanely huge amount of time.

I've tried substituting the "outlook.office365" domain with their IP address but somehow that just makes things even **slower**.

Is there any way I can speed this up?

Comment: How many messages do you have in that mailbox?

Comment: You could try to print timestamps between the steps to narrow down which step(s) take a long time.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy There's only 8 in the inbox but there's tonnes in other subfolders.

Comment: It seems to be imap_open that takes so long, because I can actually just do that and it takes about the same time

Comment: You might attempt using a tool like socat to see if the connection is taking forever, or the login.  Perhaps their authentication infrastructure is slow or overloaded.